# Asymptotic freedom and momentum exchange

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, strong-force, confinement

Why is the momentum exchange very high for low distances?

> For sufficiently short distances or large exchanges of momentum
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_freedom

While I think about it.. what exactly is exchanging momentum? The quarks?

Comment: Yes, the quarks.

Comment: [de Broglie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave#de_Broglie_relations).

Comment: De Broglie? Does that mean the quarks are exchanging momenta all the time? Like scattering processes?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the de Broglie relation,

$$\lambda = \frac{h}{p},$$

wavelength and momentum are inversely proportional. This means that small distances are connected to large momenta and long distances are related to small momenta.